# xsltc: how to embed XML files in DLL

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

I use xsltc.exe in developer console (ms visual studio). I try to generate a DLL that could be used in a .NET project.

```
xsltc /settings:dtd /settings:document /settings:script  /c:Bk24.Specs  specs.xsl  /out:Bk24Specs.dll
```

I have successfully generated many of such DLLs before, but now I have a big problem. The current XSL contains a reference to an XML

```
<xsl:variable name="spcodes" select="document('specialCodes.xml')/list/data" />
```

I successfully generated the DLL for this template. I added a reference to this DLL in the .NET project. But then, the application throws an exception

> File not found (c:\projects\bk24\specialCodes.xml)

in the real production environment. Of course, on the client's workstation there is no such directory `C:\projects\bk24\`. It's my directory on my dev machine, but when I ran xsltc.exe, I put specialCodes.xml into the same directory  where the XSL is placed. I hoped that xsltc.exe would look at the directory, found that XSLs and XMLs are in the same directory, so, the generator will embed the XMLs into this DLL, but, it seems, it's not...

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: What you can do in XSLT is inline the other XML as a parameter or variable e.g. `<xsl:variable name="spcodes-rtf"><list><data>a</data><data>b</data></list></xsl:variable>` and then use (for XSLT 1 like XslCompiledTransform supports) `<xsl:variable name="spcodes" xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common" select="exslt:node-set($spcodes-rtf)/list/data"/>`.

Comment: You can make the xml a resource.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/sharepoint/how-to-add-a-resource-file?view=vs-2019

Comment: @MartinHonnen thank you very much!  This is exactly that helped me!

Answer (score 1):

If it is only a read only file, then open the file in a text editor and copy it. Then embed it as a string in any cs class and read with `XElement.Parse(that_string)`